# Using Entity framework's code first reverse engineering - entity and business classes

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

After reverse engineering code first, I got entity classes and mapping. Most of the business classes (that I already have) have the same name as entity classes and most of the properties in entity and business classes are the same.

If I understand the implementation right, I should make partial classes with entity classes having all the properties and change the business classes by removing those properties and leaving only the business rules.

If that is correct, what to do about derived classes? Obviously entity classes need all properties from base class. Can I change the code in the entity classes so that the entity classes also inherit from the base classes?

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should remove your business classes. ORM is tool for loading and persisting objects - you don't have special set of objects for persistence and special set of objects for business logic. Use single set which consists of persisted properties and computed properties + business rules executed on persisted properties (store them in partial class). That will form something which is commonly called domain object - it has both data and logic related to its data. You can have separate classes performing logic on multiple domain objects (so the logic doesn't belong to the object itself). These classes are commonly called domain services.

Comment: Thank you, that is the way I'm looking at it as well, but since business classes are not "my property", was hesitant to do any changes to them. I'll present this idea to my fellow workers.

Answer (score 0):

are you saying that `most of the properties in entity and business classes are the same` ? It shouldn't be like that. Business classes should have only the business logic not the properties of entities. Business class will use entity classes to fulfill the business.
Here is a good example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8/

Comment: This is the new project, so database and class properties are pretty much in sync. Decision to use Entity framework was made late at the project.

Comment: See I have added an example. Try to make changes according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the link, could not open the project, not sure which prerequisites needs, will look into it. Any thoughts on inheritance?

Comment: can you post more details about your project. (layers, patterns etc)

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I do not see there is too much that you could see from the code I might post.